# sql query wont send to database php

Tags: php, mysql, sql-server

I am not able to check my voucher to the database. I think my sql query for $VouchExist is wrong, I have tried everything. Do I have the correct syntax? I want to check if the user entered voucher exists in the database. I have multiple vouchers in the the database.

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors',1);
include_once 'includes/db_connect.php';
include_once 'includes/functions.php';
sec_session_start();

if (login_check($mysqli) == true) {
        $logged = 'accessing';
} else {
        $logged = 'not accessing';
}
$username = $_SESSION['username'];
$getemail = mysqli_query($mysqli, "SELECT email FROM members WHERE username = '$username' ");
$email = '';
while($gear = mysqli_fetch_array( $getemail )) {
        $email = $gear['email'];
} 


$userVouch = $_POST['vouchercheck'];
echo $userVouch;

$VouchExist = mysqli_query($mysqli, "SELECT voucher FROM vouchers WHERE voucher = '$userVouch' ");


if(isset($_POST['seatme'])){
        if(!empty($_POST['flight'])){
                foreach($_POST['flight'] as $key=>$selected){
                    echo "<p>You have selected seat: ".$selected."</p>";
                }
        }
} 


if (empty($VouchExist)) 
{
        print 'BUT there is no voucher, Please Enter a voucher.<br>';

}
else {
        $var = 1;
        if ( $result = mysqli_query($mysqli, "INSERT INTO seating (flight_id, email, seat_id) VALUES ('$var', '$email', '$selected')"))
        {
                echo "<font color='green'>Successfully taken seat.<br>";
                echo "<br/><a href='user.php'>Back to seating</a>";
        }
        else{
                print 'something wrong here<br>';
        }
}
?>
```

This is user.php which connects the vouchers

```
    <?php
include_once 'includes/db_connect.php';
include_once 'includes/functions.php';
 ini_set('display_errors',"1");
sec_session_start();
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
        <meta name="description" content="">
        <meta name="author" content="">



        <title>Secure Login: Plane Create</title>
    <!-- Bootstrap core CSS -->
    <link href="vendor/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- Custom styles for this template -->
    <link href="css/user.css" rel="stylesheet">
    </head>
    <body>
        <!-- Navigation -->
    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark bg-dark fixed-top">
      <div class="container">
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="index.php">Airways</a>
        <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarResponsive" aria-controls="navbarResponsive" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
          <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
        </button>
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarResponsive">
          <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
            <li class="nav-item active">
              <a class="nav-link" href="index.php">Home
                <span class="sr-only">(current)</span>
              </a>
            </li>
            <?php if (login_check($mysqli) == true && $_SESSION['username'] == "admin"):?> 

<li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link" href="protected_page.php">Plane Control</a>
            </li>


<?php elseif (login_check($mysqli) == true  && $_SESSION['username'] != "admin") : ?>

<li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link" href="user.php">Plane</a>
            </li>

<?php else: ?>
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link" href="register.php">Plane</a>
            </li>
<?php endif; ?>
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link" href="#">Account</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link" href="register.php">Login</a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
    </nav>





    <?php if (login_check($mysqli) == true && $_SESSION['username'] == "admin"):?> 

      <!-- Page Content -->
    <div class="container">

      <div class="row">

        <div class="col-lg-3">
          <h1 class="my-4">Admin Panel</h1>
          <div class="list-group">
            <div class="btn-group-horizontal ">
          <a href="protected_page.php" class="btn btn-Primary" role="button">Admin Page</a><br>
          <a href="user.php" class="btn btn-Primary" role="button">User Page</a><br>
          <a href="index.php" class="btn btn-Primary" role="button">HomePage</a><br>
          </div>
          </div>
        </div>


    <?php elseif (login_check($mysqli) == true  && $_SESSION['username'] != "admin") : ?>
     <!-- Page Content -->
    <div class="container">

      <div class="row">

        <div class="col-lg-3">
          <h1 class="my-4">User Panel</h1>
          <div class="list-group">
          <a href="user.php" class="btn btn-Primary" role="button">User Page</a><br>
          <a href="index.php" class="btn btn-Primary" role="button">HomePage</a><br>
          </div>
        </div>
        <!-- /.col-lg-3 -->

      <?php else: ?>
            <p>
                <span class="error">You are not authorized to access this page.</span> Please <a href="index.php">login</a>.
            </p>
        <?php endif; ?>

    <?php if (login_check($mysqli) == true) : ?>
        <div class="col-lg-9">

          <div class="card mt-4">
            <div class="card-body">
              <h3 class="card-title" style="text-align: center;">Select your seats and flights below</h3>
              <h4>Steps:</h4>
              <p class="card-text">



            <p>Welcome <?php echo htmlentities($_SESSION['username']); ?>!</p>
            <p>
               -First scroll below and select you flight,<br>
               -Then select which seats,<br>
               -Then press submit<br>
            </p>


            <p>Return to <a href="index.php">homepage</a></p>

              </p>
            </div>
          </div>
         <!-- /.card -->

          <div class="card card-outline-secondary my-4 text-center">
            <div class="card-header">
              Order a seat ticket
            </div>






                <div class="plane">
  <div class="cockpit" >
    <h1>Please select a seat</h1>
  </div>
  <div class="exit exit--front fuselage text-center">
  </div>
  <form action="flightselect.php" method="post" name="form"> 
    <td>Please Enter Voucher</td>
    <td><input type="text" name="vouchercheck"></td>
  <ol class="cabin fuselage">
    <li class="row row--1" style="padding-right: 100%;">
      <ol class="seats" type="A" ">
        <li class="seat">
          <input type="radio" name="flight[]" id="1A" value="1A" />
          <label for="1A">1A</label>
        </li>
        <li class="seat">
          <input type="radio" name="flight[]" id="1B" value="1B" />
          <label for="1B">1B</label>
        </li>
        <li class="seat">
          <input type="radio" name="flight[]" id="1C" value="1C" />
          <label for="1C">1C</label>
        </li>
        <li class="seat">
          <input type="radio" name="flight[]" id="1D" value="1D" />
          <label for="1D">1D</label>
        </li>
        <li class="seat">
          <input type="radio" name="flight[]" id="1E" value="1E" />
          <label for="1E">1E</label>
        </li>
        <li class="seat">
          <input type="radio" name="flight[]" id="1F" value="1F" />
          <label for="1F">1F</label>
        </li>
      </ol>
    </li>
    <li class="row row--2" style="padding-right: 100%;">
      <ol class="seats" type="A">
        <li class="seat">
          <input type="radio" name="flight[]" id="2A" value="2A" />
          <label for="2A">2A</label>
        </li>
        <li class="seat">
          <input type="radio" name="flight[]" id="2B" value="2B" />
          <label for="2B">2B</label>
        </li>
        <li class="seat">
          <input type="radio" name="flight[]" id="2C" value="2C" />
          <label for="2C">2C</label>
        </li>
        <li class="seat">
          <input type="radio" name="flight[]" id="2D" value="2D" />
          <label for="2D">2D</label>
        </li>
        <li class="seat">
          <input type="radio" name="flight[]" id="2E" value="2E" />
          <label for="2E">2E</label>
        </li>
        <li class="seat">
          <input type="radio" name="flight[]" id="2F" value="2F" />
          <label for="2F">2F</label>
        </li>
      </ol>
    </li>
    <li class="row row--3" style="padding-right: 100%;">
      <ol class="seats" type="A">
        <li class="seat">
          <input type="radio" name="flight[]" id="3A" value="3A" />
          <label for="3A">3A</label>
        </li>
        <li class="seat">
          <input type="radio" name="flight[]" id="3B" value="3B" />
          <label for="3B">3B</label>
        </li>
        <li class="seat">
          <input type="radio" name="flight[]" id="3C" value="3C" />
          <label for="3C">3C</label>
        </li>
        <li class="seat">
          <input type="radio" name="flight[]" id="3D" value="3D" />
          <label for="3D">3D</label>
        </li>
        <li class="seat">
          <input type="radio" name="flight[]" id="3E" value="3E" />
          <label for="3E">3E</label>
        </li>
        <li class="seat">
          <input type="radio" name="flight[]" id="3F" value="3F" />
          <label for="3F">3F</label>
        </li>
      </ol>
    </li>
    <li class="row row--4" style="padding-right: 100%;">
      <ol class="seats" type="A">
        <li class="seat">
          <input type="radio" name="flight[]" id="4A" value="4A" />
          <label for="4A">4A</label>
        </li>
        <li class="seat">
          <input type="radio" name="flight[]" id="4B" value="4B" />
          <label for="4B">4B</label>
        </li>
        <li class="seat">
          <input type="radio" name="flight[]" id="4C" value="4C" />
          <label for="4C">4C</label>
        </li>
        <li class="seat">
          <input type="radio" name="flight[]" id="4D" value="4D" />
          <label for="4D">4D</label>
        </li>
        <li class="seat">
          <input type="radio" name="flight[]" id="4E" value="4E" />
          <label for="4E">4E</label>
        </li>
        <li class="seat">
          <input type="radio" name="flight[]" id="4F" value="4F" />
          <label for="4F">4F</label>
        </li>
      </ol>
    </li>
    <li class="row row--5" style="padding-right: 100%;">
      <ol class="seats" type="A">
        <li class="seat">
          <input type="radio" name="flight[]" id="5A" value="5A" />
          <label for="5A">5A</label>
        </li>
        <li class="seat">
          <input type="radio" name="flight[]" id="5B" value="5B" />
          <label for="5B">5B</label>
        </li>
        <li class="seat">
          <input type="radio" name="flight[]" id="5C" value="5C" />
          <label for="5C">5C</label>
        </li>
        <li class="seat">
          <input type="radio" name="flight[]" id="5D" value="5D" />
          <label for="5D">5D</label>
        </li>
        <li class="seat">
          <input type="radio" name="flight[]" id="5E" value="5E" />
          <label for="5E">5E</label>
        </li>
        <li class="seat">
          <input type="radio" name="flight[]" id="5F" value="5F" />
          <label for="5F">5F</label>
        </li>
      </ol>
    </li>
    <li class="row row--6" style="padding-right: 100%;">
      <ol class="seats" type="A">
        <li class="seat">
          <input type="radio" name="flight[]" id="6A" value="6A" />
          <label for="6A">6A</label>
        </li>
        <li class="seat">
          <input type="radio" name="flight[]" id="6B" value="6B" />
          <label for="6B">6B</label>
        </li>
        <li class="seat">
          <input type="radio" name="flight[]" id="6C" value="6C" />
          <label for="6C">6C</label>
        </li>
        <li class="seat">
          <input type="radio" name="flight[]" id="6D" value="6D" />
          <label for="6D">6D</label>
        </li>
        <li class="seat">
          <input type="radio" name="flight[]" id="6E" value="6E" />
          <label for="6E">6E</label>
        </li>
        <li class="seat">
          <input type="radio" name="flight[]" id="6F" value="6F" />
          <label for="6F">6F</label>
        </li>
      </ol>
    </li>
    <li class="row row--7" style="padding-right: 100%;">
      <ol class="seats" type="A">
        <li class="seat">
          <input type="radio" name="flight[]" id="7A" value="7A" />
          <label for="7A">7A</label>
        </li>
        <li class="seat">
          <input type="radio" name="flight[]" id="7B" value="7B" />
          <label for="7B">7B</label>
        </li>
        <li class="seat">
          <input type="radio" name="flight[]" id="7C" value="7C" />
          <label for="7C">7C</label>
        </li>
        <li class="seat">
          <input type="radio" name="flight[]" id="7D" value="7D" />
          <label for="7D">7D</label>
        </li>
        <li class="seat">
          <input type="radio" name="flight[]" id="7E" value="7E" />
          <label for="7E">7E</label>
        </li>
        <li class="seat">
          <input type="radio" name="flight[]" id="7F" value="7F" />
          <label for="7F">7F</label>
        </li>
      </ol>
    </li>
    <li class="row row--8" style="padding-right: 100%;">
      <ol class="seats" type="A">
        <li class="seat">
          <input type="radio" name="flight[]" id="8A" value="8A" />
          <label for="8A">8A</label>
        </li>
        <li class="seat">
          <input type="radio" name="flight[]" id="8B" value="8B" />
          <label for="8B">8B</label>
        </li>
        <li class="seat">
          <input type="radio" name="flight[]" id="8C" value="8C" />
          <label for="8C">8C</label>
        </li>
        <li class="seat">
          <input type="radio" name="flight[]" id="8D" value="8D" />
          <label for="8D">8D</label>
        </li>
        <li class="seat">
          <input type="radio" name="flight[]" id="8E" value="8E" />
          <label for="8E">8E</label>
        </li>
        <li class="seat">
          <input type="radio" name="flight[]" id="8F" value="8F" />
          <label for="8F">8F</label>
        </li>
      </ol>
    </li>
    <li class="row row--9" style="padding-right: 100%;">
      <ol class="seats" type="A">
        <li class="seat">
          <input type="radio" name="flight[]" id="9A" value="9A" />
          <label for="9A">9A</label>
        </li>
        <li class="seat">
          <input type="radio" name="flight[]" id="9B" value="9B" />
          <label for="9B">9B</label>
        </li>
        <li class="seat">
          <input type="radio" name="flight[]" id="9C" value="9C" />
          <label for="9C">9C</label>
        </li>
        <li class="seat">
          <input type="radio" name="flight[]" id="9D" value="9D" />
          <label for="9D">9D</label>
        </li>
        <li class="seat">
          <input type="radio" name="flight[]" id="9E" value="9E" />
          <label for="9E">9E</label>
        </li>
        <li class="seat">
          <input type="radio" name="flight[]" id="9F" value="9F" />
          <label for="9F">9F</label>
        </li>
      </ol>
    </li>
    <li class="row row--10" style="padding-right: 4%";>
      <ol class="seats" type="A">
        <li class="seat">
          <input type="radio" name="flight[]" id="10A" value="10A" />
          <label for="10A">10A</label>
        </li>
        <li class="seat">
          <input type="radio" name="flight[]" id="10B" value="10B" />
          <label for="10B">10B</label>
        </li>
        <li class="seat">
          <input type="radio" name="flight[]" id="10C" value="10C" />
          <label for="10C">10C</label>
        </li>
        <li class="seat">
          <input type="radio" name="flight[]" id="10D" value="10D" />
          <label for="10D">10D</label>
        </li>
        <li class="seat">
          <input type="radio" name="flight[]" id="10E" value="10E" />
          <label for="10E">10E</label>
        </li>
        <li class="seat">
          <input type="radio" name="flight[]" id="10F" value="10F" />
          <label for="10F">10F</label>
        </li>
      </ol>
    </li>
  </ol>
  <div class="exit exit--back fuselage">    
  </div>
</div>
<input type="submit" name="seatme" value="Submit" style="font-weight: bold;">
</form>



          </div>
          <!-- /.card -->

        </div>
        <!-- /.col-lg-9 -->

      </div>



    </div>
    <!-- /.container -->

    </body>

<!-- Footer -->
    <footer class="py-5 bg-dark">
      <div class="container">
        <p class="m-0 text-center text-white">Copyright &copy; Matthew, Stephen, Nick</p>
      </div>
      <!-- /.container -->
    </footer>

    <!-- Bootstrap core JavaScript -->
    <script src="vendor/jquery/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="vendor/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>

        <?php else : ?>
            <p>
                <span class="error">You are not authorized to access this page.</span> Please <a href="index.php">login</a>.
            </p>
        <?php endif; ?>
</html>
```

Comment: First you are directly running query against unsanitized user input. Also it would be helpfull if you can attach error logs to go with code for us to help you better :)

Comment: any suggestions?

Comment: I still don't see the error logs to go with the code :) . That is to help debug the code faster to see where you are going wrong .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For an accurate answer, I need more details like table structure / sample data. But for the time being, better you change your query as below

```
$VouchExist = mysqli_query($mysqli, "SELECT voucher FROM vouchers WHERE voucher = '".$userVouch."' ");
```

Or you can debug the query by echoing the query as below

```
echo "SELECT voucher FROM vouchers WHERE voucher = '$userVouch' ";
```

Hope this will fix your issue. You are welcome for any further comments

Comment: I did what you said and now its just sending it to database even though there isnt even a matching voucher. i also updated my code above

Comment: You can simply debug the query by echoing the query as below
`echo "SELECT voucher FROM vouchers WHERE voucher = '".$userVouch."'";`

Comment: @Pramod both the query mentioned by op and you will execute to give the same result. That won't make any difference.